# APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST for MobileFirst 8.0 Security Authentication?

Tags: java, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am receiving this error when I attempt to authenticate to my Security Check:

```
errorCode: "APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST"
errorMsg: "Application doesn't exist"
```

Here is the error in the server log:

> [10/18/16 13:59:32:991 CDT] 00001447 m.mfp.server.registration.internal.rest.RegistrationEndpoint E Failed to process registration request.
>       com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.MFPRESTException: 400; headers=[]; body={ errorCode=APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST errorMsg=Application doesn't exist}
>           at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.internal.context.ClientSecurityContextImpl.load(ClientSecurityContextImpl.java:178)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor179.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

I used the [UserLogin adapter](http://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/SecurityCheckAdapters/blob/release80/UserLogin/src/main/java/com/sample/UserLogin.java).

I also used the [UserLoginChallengeHandler.js](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PreemptiveLoginCordova/blob/release80/www/js/UserLoginChallengeHandler.js) to handle logging-in.

The UserLogin adapter appears in the MobileFirst Console:

[image: Screenshot of MFP console]

I am unsure what this error means.  Google shows no results for this error.

Comment: From the error message it looks like the application is not present in the console. Ensure that the version number and package name match exactly as it is in the application.

Comment: Register the application using the mfpdev cli. That minimises chances of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this relates to the security check at all...

As mentioned by Norton, the error is just that - the identifier of the application is not present, in its correct form, in the server.

And as mentioned by Vivin, by using the MobileFirst CLI to register the application (instead of doing so manually via the console), you can minimize the chance of registration "failure" (i.e. incorrectly registering the application).

It could be that when registering the application, you incorrectly entered its version number. Perhaps you've used "1.0" instead of "1.0.0.".

So you can check the following:

1. The version (can be found in the config.xml file)
2. The application identifier (can also be found in the config.xml file)

Or use the CLI, from the root folder of the Cordova app: `mfpdev app register`.

Comment: I registered using mfpdev CLI.  I believe the issue was that I accidentally used "cordova prepare" from the adapter folder, which messed up the project.  I reverted my code and was able to get the UserLogin to work as expected.  I will accept this as the answer, since it did hint to a broken project.